# The "Tools" Option in my visual studio code is missing

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I was trying to make some changes in the visual studio code and was looking for Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio Code via start-menu search on my Windows device but it isn't there.

So I decided to alternatively instead look for it in the Tools Menu but there is no Tools option on my device. How do I bring the tools option?

[image: MY VS Code]]

Comment: I don't think VSC has a Tools Menu.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a tools menu in VS code.

A screenshot from the [official VS Code site.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility):

[image: From the VS code site]

You can check this by searching for Visual Studio Code in Google images. All of the screenshots show there is no tools menu.

Answer (score 0):

You might be confused between Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code, which are two entirely different softwares. Visual Studio has a 'Tools' option in it's tool bar where as Visual Studio Code does not have a `Tools` option.